# undefined reference to "***"

Tags: c++, c++11, linker

I have defined a class Cat which has a member function void Cat::miao() in Cat.h file. Then , I implement this function in Cat.cpp as the following code.

However, while compiling and linking, I got an error , say , "undefined reference to `Cat::miao()" .What wrong with the code?

My compiler is GNU c11.

-----Cat.h

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
class Cat
{
    string name;
    public:
        Cat(const string&n):name(n){};
        void miao();
};
```

-----Cat.cpp

```
#include"Cat.h"
void Cat::miao()
{
    cout << name << endl;
}
```

-----main.cpp

```
#include"Cat.h"
int main()
{
    Cat tom("tom");
    tom.miao();
    return 1;
}
```

Compiling with:

```
g++ main.cpp
```

results in this error:

> C:\Users****:K.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x69): undefined reference to `Cat::
>   miao()'
>   collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: This looks like a linking problem - can you paste the exact command used to compile(/link) your program?

Comment: Command "g++ main.cpp" in windows 8

Comment: You're not compiling the `Cat.cpp`. Try `g++ main.cpp Cat.cpp`

Comment: @W.Cameron You need to add `cat.cpp`, e.g., `g++ main.cpp cat.cpp`.

Comment: @W.Cameron  check the answer it will work .

Answer (score 2):

Cat.cpp is not being properly linked to main.cpp in the final linking part of the compilation process.

Compiling using the command `g++ main.cpp` will attempt to compile and link main.cpp. Cat.cpp is not being compiled and linked to main.cpp because you did not specify its name on the command line.

Probable fix : Use `g++ main.cpp Cat.cpp` when compiling.

It is also recommended that you setup a Makefile or another build manager if you plan on making a big project, though if you're just doing this for a tutorial and are going to throw this code away in 5 minutes, this is not really needed.

Comment: Yes, you definitely right. I try command "g++ main.cpp cat.cpp" and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

-----Cat.h

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
class Cat
{
    string name;
    public:
        Cat(const string&n):name(n){};
        void miao();
};
```

-----Cat.cpp

```
#include"Cat.h"
void Cat::miao()
{
    cout << name << endl;
}
```

-----main.cpp

```
#include"Cat.h"
int main()
{
    Cat tom("tom");
    tom.miao();
    return 1;
}
```

Compiling with:

```
g++ main.cpp  cat.cpp
```

---

### And surely it will work.